# Passing Parameters to AngularJS $http Factory

Tags: angularjs

I created a factory for $http as below

```
TestApp.factory('TestHttpFactory', function ($http) { 
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.domain.com/api/get_item/?item_id=:id',
        params: { id: '@id' }
    });
});
```

In the controller I need to get the value returned by the API (as below).  To get the data and use it in code I am using the success method which works fine:

```
var MyCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $http,   $routeParams,  TestHttpFactory) {

    TestHttpFactory
        .success(function (data) { 
            $scope.item =  data;
            //do something with $scope.item
    }); 
};
```

However, I am unsure of how to pass a parameter to the factory, the below fails with the error : *object is not a function*.

```
TestHttpFactory({id : $routeParams.id})
        .success(function (data) { 
            $scope.item =  data; 
    });
```

How should I pass the parameters to the factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cant since you are taking an invoked function. lets refactor your 'Factory'/Service

```
TestApp.factory('TestHttpFactory', function ($http) { 
    return function(id){
         return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://www.domain.com/api/get_item/?item_id=:id',
           params: { id: id }
         });

    }
});
```

then in your controller you can do

```
var MyCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $http,   $routeParams,  TestHttpFactory) {

    TestHttpFactory(1234)
        .success(function (data) { 
            $scope.item =  data;
            //do something with $scope.item
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly, originally the return was not an $http object but rather the invoked $get method on the $http object.

Comment: correct $http is the service $http() is the service invocation that returns a specific type of deferred with the succes and error methods at that point the $http request has already been made, you can not alter it so you needed to either get your hand on the actual $hht from your cotnroller and make the call from there or use a proxy function that takes aparmeter and makes the call for you. this is actually kind of what the $resource service do, you should probably look into that if you don't require the low level handling that $hhtp provides